# Webaudio oscillator stop() callback

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

When calling stop() on a web audio oscillator, the oscillator node just hangs around, disconnected and unused.

If I tell an oscillator to stop in 2 seconds:

```
oscillator.stop( audioCtx.currentTime + 2 );
```

Is there a way to set a callback so I can delete the oscillator immediately after stop() has ran ?

I thought about using a setTimeout with the stop time plus half a second or so but that may end up deleting the wrong oscillator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oscillator nodes support the [onended](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-OscillatorNode-onended) event that is called when the oscillator ends (stops).

Comment: This is most likely what you're looking for. +1

Comment: I think this is the closest to a callback that is possible, only problem is onended does not seem to allow a parameter to be passed to the function it calls.

Comment: Create a closure for the event handler that contains the parameter you want? I assume the parameter you're looking for is, basically, the index into the array that holds all of your nodes so you can remove it from the array.

Comment: I totally forgot about this.

Comment: Thanks for the closure suggestion, that's solved my problem!

Here's the code...

`var self = this;
var noteEndCallback = function(){delete self.notes[note];}
this.notes[note].onended = noteEndCallback;`

Answer (score 2):

Why do you even keep a reference to the oscillator around?  If you release your reference to the oscillator immediately after calling stop(), the WA system will keep it around until it completes, then it will get garbage collected automatically.  You don't need to hold on to it yourself.

Comment: Here's the reason I'm keeping a reference to it:

I have a polyphonic synth with a playNote() function and a stopNote() function which both receive a note number and a time, when playNote is called, the note will keep on playing forever until stopNote is called for that note.  Because it's polyphonic, one note could be playing constantly whilst several others have started and finished within the same time.

Comment: All the note oscillators currently playing are stored in an array and removed once stopNote is called for that note.  I also have a stopAll() function which loops through that array and stops everything.

Comment: Right, I understand why you're storing the oscillators while the notes are playing.  But once you schedule the stop(), you don't need to keep a reference to the note.  Just release it.

Comment: The note could be scheduled to stop in say 6 seconds, but I also have a master stop button that needs to stop everything currently playing immediately. If I get rid of the reference to note osc, it will keep playing for a few seconds after the master stop button has been pressed.

Comment: Hmm, I see.  But then you don't need very precise scheduling (since you're just remembering to clean up your oscillator handle), right?  Just set a timeout, and use bind() to make sure it's the right oscillator.